# Calculated Column - Formular for AND & OR combination needed

Tags: calculated-column

Need help with a tricky calculated field formula

Here is the detail pseudo code:

> If Contract Type = On Contract Growth
>
> or Contract Type = Extension Renewal
>
> and TnC Change = No and Fin Pro = Yes set value to Yes
>
> else set value to No

I tried the below formula

```
=IF(OR([Contract Type]="Extension Renewal",
[Contract Type]="On Contract Growth",
IF(AND([TnC Change]="No",[Fin Pro]="Yes"),"Yes","No")))
```

But got an error while using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one :

`=IF(AND(OR([Contract Type]="Extension Renewal",[Contract Type]="On Contract Growth"),[TnC Change]="No",[Fin Pro]="Yes"),"Yes","No"`)